# CommandButton not invoked when changing pre populated values

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Anyone can please help me I am getting a weird issue I have list of records in `datatable` now i selected a record and click on Edit button now this selected record will be shown to popup window.

Now issue is that if i will edit selected value populated by previous window and press submit button page refreshing but action not invoked,but if i will change those value which not coming from parent Window or empty field in Popup Window then `commandButton` action Invoked.

Any one please tell me what the issue. What i am missing?

**Parent Window** is `Session Scoped`
**Pop Window** is `View Scoped`

```
  JSF Version          2.1.13
  Richfaces Version    4.3.5.Final
  Javax.el             3.0.0
  Servlet              2.4
  el-api               2.2
  el-impl              2.2
  Jboss                7.1.0.Final
```

**EDIT:-**

PopUpWindow CommandButton Code

```
<a4j:commandButton
                    action="#{addFeaturePopUpBean.addFeature(parentBean)}"
                    value="#{bsmPortalLabel['button.common.submit']}"
                    image="/resources/images/submit-arrow.png"
                    render="cfsCreate,createRfs,createReso,notification,search-filter"  >
                    <rich:tooltip id="toolemsSubmit" layout="block" >
                        <span style="white-space: nowrap">
                            #{bsmPortalLabel['tooltip.common.submit']}</span>
                    </rich:tooltip>
                </a4j:commandButton>
```

**EDIT1 :-**

Exact Cause of the problem if i am using component link this

```
<h:inputText style="width:142px" id="featureName"
                                        value="#{addFeaturePopUpBean.featuesObj.name}"
                                        immediate="true"
                                        validatorMessage="#{bsmPortalMessage['message.catalog.validation.compositeChar.name']}">
                                        <f:validateRequired />
                                        <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$"></f:validateRegex>
                                        <f:ajax event="blur" execute="featureName" render="msg1" />
                                    </h:inputText>
                                    <h:message id="msg1" for="featureName" style="color:red" />
```

Then `commandButton` invoked but if i will remove `<f:ajax event="blur" execute="featureName" render="msg1" />` from the `textBox` now command **not** invoked .

But right now i am not able to figure out  why this is happening?

Comment: You need post the commandButton code, want to see your render attribute.

Comment: @AmitBhati added command button code

Comment: The ids in render attribute, are they present in the same form as that of popup or in different form?

Comment: @AmitBhati few are in same Popup and few Parent window

Comment: so nested forms right ?

Comment: Yes Popup Window include the Parent Window But everything working fine but issue with edit only and with pre populated values not other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87718/discussion-between-amit-bhati-and-subodh-joshi).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info This code is not in MCVE flavor, so the cause is not immediately visible. And all that unprofessional begging/whining and posting multiple questions about the same problem is disturbing.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for update